# OWIN Startup Class Called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

Am having a design crisis.

I have few things which have to remain static during my application lifetime.

A `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method in Startup.cs class is being called ore than once, Also they appear to be multiple instances of "static" variables.

I have this on my startup class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
```

Am also using these parkages

```
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

How can i insure that the configuration in startup.cs is executed only once?

Comment: I think you can use ApplicationStart of the Global.asax instead of Owin's Configuration

Comment: What makes you suspect it is getting called more than once ? If you followed the OWIN docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), you would be have a code similar to this - `WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);` which you would be calling it once.

Comment: Check if you are running your app in a web garden? Possibly this is called multiple times, by multiple worker processes

Comment: @zaitsman I dont think so... I am on IIS Express in visual studio

Comment: @Subbu I am using breakpoints in visual studio

Comment: @Subbu I had a quick look.. It runs in IIS.. So i dont have static main to put `WebApp.Start<Startup>`

Comment: @S.Petrosov Global.asx have the same behavior.

Comment: @konzo Application_Start is being called only once. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: @S.Petrosov Mhh Strange... It is being called exactly twice.. I suspect there is somethings to do with my packages

Comment: @zaitsman your comment is the correct answer you see i set my iis express site to run on  `http://localhost:65089/Transactions`  but for some reasons it was also accepting request to `http://localhost:65089/` now there was this external client which was sending request to the later causing a second worker process to spawn...

Comment: @konzo Please share here how you have solved this. I too am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me with startup running exactly twice.
The problem was this

```
<add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
```

I removed this line from config and that fixed it

[image]